# Does there exist a formula to calculate $2.357137939171\ldots$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, prime-numbers, transcendence-theory

So I was messing with polynomials and I encountered the following equation: $$26214x^3 - 27761x^2 - 71019x - 21667 = 0.$$ Solving for $x$ using the cubic formula, I got three solutions (as expected, pursuant to the FTOA, namely, the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra).

Let's call the equation $p(x)$ and I will denote by $p(x)_n$ the $n^{\text{th}}$ root of $p(x)$.

$p(x)_{1,2}<0$ but $p(x)_3>0$. In fact, $$p(x)_3 = 2.3571379391713739171440\ldots$$ Notice that we begin with the first four primes $2,3,5,7$ and then we go to $1,3,7,9$. Also notice that the next four primes after $7$ are $11,13,17,19$. That's when I realised that $p(x)_3$ has its decimal places being the last digit of primes, apart from $4,4,0$.

> > **Question:**
>
> Let $d_n$ be the last digit of the $n^{\text{th}}$ prime, then is the decimal $2.d_2d_3d_4\ldots$ *transcendental*? Does it have a formula? Can a formula be constructed?

---

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Tyler6 hahah thank you for he edit. Me thinking about prime numbers has confused myself :)

Comment: No worries, we’ve all been there ahah

Comment: Here's the continued fraction for $0.23571379\dots$: http://oeis.org/A071775

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks for that, but both decimals are not quite the same :)

Comment: I don't know what you mean. We're talking about the decimal made from the last digit of the primes, right? That's what the OEIS reference is about, too.

Comment: @GerryMyerson lol sorry. Multiply $0.23571379...$ by $10$. *facepalm*

Answer (score 4):

Transcendence beats me, but I have a proof for irrationality:

To begin, notice that other than the primes $2$ or $5$, no prime can end in any of $0$, $2$, $4$, $5$, $6$ or $8$, since this would imply divisibility by $2$ or $5$. Therefore we see that for all primes other than those two, they must end with either $1$, $3$, $7$, or $9$.

Shiu proved (https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1112/S0024610799007863) that if $a$ and $q$ are coprime integers, there exist arbitrary long strings of prime congruent to $a \bmod q$. For our purpose, this implies that in our number, $2.a_1a_2...$, there exist arbitrary long strings of $1$s, $3$s, $7$s, and $9$s. This is sufficient to prove it cannot be rational.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts. I found it rather trivial it was irrational since there are infinitely many primes, so infinitely many decimal places. And, given some formulas by Hardy and Littlewood, we know that there are not infinitely many primes continuing with a certain digit from *in a row*, so the decimal would not be terminating. Nonetheless, $(+1)$ :)

Comment: In 1946, Paul Erdos and Arthur Herbert Copeland proved that his number is normal in base 10. Hence it is also known as the Edros-Copeland constant.

Comment: @NilotpalKantiSinha the Copeland Erdös Constant is the concatenation of all primes, this is the concatenation of only their last digits

Comment: It’s a small difference but the Copeland Erdös Constant being was a result of a more general theorem and relied on the constant being a concatenation of increasing integers which were sufficiently dense. However since this new number isn’t an increasing concatenation normality is no longer known

Comment: Actually, normality is known, this is non normal. Normality would imply that all digits 0 to 9 would have equal probability of appearing, but more than half of these digits never appear.

Comment: "I found it rather trivial it was irrational since there are infinitely many primes, so infinitely many decimal places." By that logic, $1/3=.333\dots$ is irrational, since it has infinitely many decimal places.

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes but $1/3$ is terminating :)

Comment: No, it isn't. $1/4=.25$ is terminating; $1/3=.333\dots$ is periodic. Is it really trivial that $.23571379\dots$ is not periodic?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I guess that's the right word then -- I meant periodic. Read my first comment most above. Hardy ad Littlewood essentially proved that it isn't periodic.

Comment: @user, you've lost me. What did Hardy & Littlewood do, that "essentially" proves this decimal is not periodic?

Comment: @GerryMyerson So they proved that there do not exist primes that end with the same last digit for eternity. Eventually, one prime will not end in the same last digit as the ones before it. The last digits hate repeating themselves. So, this decimal is not periodic because the decimal places will not be the same forever at one point. I got confused between terminating and periodic, as you say.

Comment: @user, I'm still lost. How does this prevent the decimal from endlessly repeating $\dots1379137913791379\dots$ from some point on?

Comment: @GerryMyerson because the decimal digits are the last digits of primes, but the fact that its non-terminal is proven in the answer. Answer above proves irrationality. H&L proves non-periodic. Sorry for my bad choice of explanation.

Comment: @user, I know what the digits are, I don't know what Hardy & Littlewood did that "essentially" proved that the last digits of primes can't go 1, 3, 7, 9, repeating from some point on.

Comment: @GerryMyerson there is a youtube video. I will find it and show you. Hold on a second...... ok [**here**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YVvfY_lFUZ8) it is.

Comment: @user, OK. In the first place, Hardy & Littlewood didn't prove, or even "essentially" prove, anything of the kind: they made a conjecture, a conjecture which remains unproved to this day. And if the conjecture is correct, then a prime ending in a digit $d$ is followed by a prime ending in $d$ less than one-fourth of the time. But how much less than one-fourth? The difference goes to zero as you look at more and more primes. Continued next comment....

Comment: ....But never mind – that has nothing to do with periodicity. The primes could end in 1, 1, 3, 1, 7, 1, 9, 3, 3, 7, 3, 9, 7, 7, 9, 9 repeating that pattern forever, and each digit would be followed by each other digit exactly one-fourth of the time.

Comment: @GerryMyerson ok... thank you for clearing that up, then.